# How to stop neo4j creating node if node already exists

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I've been fiddeling around with neo4j for the last couple of days, but I keep running
into one issue.
Whenever I run my code it creates an entirely new node.

[image: Issue]

As seen obove there are two "SELLER" nodes and one "BUYER,SELLER" node.
The node name is "Role" and I'd ideally want it to update if there is already a "Role" node
and only create a new node when there is no "Role" node yet.
Shown below is the query I've written in C# so far, I can't get it to stop creating new nodes.
Hopefully the gods of stackoverflow can help a young lad out. haha

```
query = query.Merge("(role:Role {roletype: $newRoleValue})")
                    .Set("role = $newRole")
                    .WithParam("newRole", new { Name = newTenderVersion.Organization.Role.ToString() })
                    .WithParam("newRoleValue", newTenderVersion.Organization.Role.ToString())
                    .Merge($"(organization)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(role)");
```

=====
EDIT:

```
query = query.Merge("(role:Role {roleType: $newRoleValue})")
                    .WithParam("newRoleValue", newTenderVersion.Organization.Role.ToString())
                    .Merge($"(organization)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(role)");
```

So I've figured out how to stop the node duplication, now the question remains.
How do I make sure that if an organization is only a SELLER, it will delete its BUYER nodes.